# How can I restrict an authenticated user from posting on behalf of someone else?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

If I am logged in as `user1` and I am accessing a `ViewSet` called `RecipeSubmissionViewSet`, the `POST` takes a `recipe_id` of the recipe the user wants to submit.  How do I ensure that `user1` does not submit `user2`'s recipe, assuming the `Recipe` model has an `owner` field on it and I can just compare it to request.user? Should I use a permission class for this or is there a better way?  I'm speaking from an backend point of view and not taking into account that the front end would of course filter out the recipes that belong to the user and only show them their own recipes.

Comment: For more clarification, can you include your models and views if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be two ways. You can filter out queryset or define permission class.

If you override `get_queryset` method like this.

```
class RecipeSubmissionViewSet(...):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Recipe.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        # you can also use filtration based on action name like this

        # if self.action == 'update':
        #      return Recipe.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        # return Recipe.objects.all()
```

User will get **404** response and will never be able to access objects other than he owns.

Second choice is permission class. You can define custom permission class and check ownership explicitly like this.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class RecipeSubmissionPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # you can also check permission here based on action
        # if view.action == 'update':
        #    pass
        return request.user.is_authenticated and obj.owner == request.user




class RecipeSubmissionViewSet(...):
    permission_classes=[RecipeSubmissionPermission]
```

In this case user will get **403** permission error.

If you use both of these methods. **404** will be preferred.

You can use whichever method you want or both of these. Permission class looks more programmatic and structured way of doing it but user will know that object with this id exists but he did not have permission to update it. But if you override queryset, user is not even be able to know if object exists or not thus more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I actually am using the `get_queryset` way but what about on a post?  What about restricting a user from post another user's recipe?  Do I now use a permission class or can I somehow leverage the `get_queryset` in a `POST`?

Comment: When user do post for updating a  recipe `get_queryset` will be automatically used to get `Recipe` instance and all the filtration will be applied. If you are doing update manually (defining some custom actions) you should use `get_object` method to get `Recipe` instance you want to update. It will automatically leverage the `get_queryset` method and return 404 if object is not owned by user.

Comment: `get_queryset()` method has no role while creation of objects. @NafeesAnwar

Comment: @JPG *the POST takes a recipe_id of the recipe the user wants to submit* I think he is trying to update.

Comment: No I am trying to create.

Comment: @Pittfall You should add some pieces of code (viewset, models) if possible for more clear answer. Form plain English, it is hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok so let's say you have a `Recipe`, you post it because you didn't finish writing it but it is NOT submitted in the `RecipeSubmission` table.  Then you `POST` (create) a `RecipeSubmission` and in the body of the view `RecipeSubmission` expects a `recipe_id`.  I don't want someone injecting a recipe_id in the body of `RecipeSubmission` for a `Recipe` that does not belong to that authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the django authentication system? Then you should be able to access `request.user` in the views and set the `owner` field accordingly.

EDIT: I think I misunderstood the question.

But [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/) could help and Nafees Anwar looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Nafees answer is pretty much the way to go.

I have been developing microservices with multitenancy to users and the rules for them(as per my projecs spec) are:

- Users cannot create items on behalf of another company/user
- Users cannot view/edit items belonging to another company.

The way I do this is simple.

To prohibit viewing/editing of someone else's stuff

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(user=request.user)
```

And to prohibit editing of someone else's stuff, this is done on a serializer

```
class SomeSerializer(...):
    def validate(self, data):
        data.pop('user', None)
        data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
```

With the above, the `get_queryset` in the viewset will always return a 404 if user1 requests user2 info.

And the `validate` function will prevent assignment. Ie. If user1 creates something assigned to user2, it will rather assign user1, this behaviour is what I needed in my application, you can always `raise serializers.ValidationError("You cannot assign stuff to user2")` instead if thats what you need instead of reassigning the user as I do in my use case. With having this logic in the `validate` you can be sure that any writable function will always carry the same behaviour for that serializer.

Hope that this helps.